how is demand of exports and imports affected by an improvement in a country's terms of trade?
When the terms of trade of a country improves, it's either because the export prices went up or import prices went down; my question is, are we assuming that the demand for exports and imports is unchanged? because it wont really be more favourable if export prices go up if your export volume goes down right? so does export/import volume stay constant at Q?
